# How can I process complex user input in python?

Tags: python, user-input

I'm a pretty new python user, working on a project that will be used by people who won't really understand how picky python can be about inputs. For the program, I need to get user input telling me how long a video is(minutes and seconds), and then I need to subtract a minute and eight seconds from that length, then print it. Is there a way I could process an input such as "5 minutes and 30 seconds"?

Comment: is not enough an integer representing seconds? I mean, can the user just type: **360** (6 minutes) ??? Or the input needs to be as verbose as **6 minutes** ???

Comment: Yes, assuming they follow the same rules, however, if you have people say `'5 minutes and 30 seconds' `and other saying `'5:30' `or yet more saying `'100 seconds'` then you'll have a problems. It really depend on if people are going to follow the same rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to check each substring in the user's input and assign them to values:

```
s = input("video length? ")

minutes, seconds = [int(x) for x in s.split() if x.isdigit()]
```

The cast `int(x)` will save them as integers if desired:

```
print(minutes) # 5
print(seconds) # 30
```

Or a regular expression solution may be:

```
import re
minutes, seconds = map(int, re.findall('\d+', s))

print(minutes) # 5 
print(seconds) # 30
```

Now you have the values to perform the resulting time calculation:

```
import datetime

# here, 100,1,1 are just placeholder values for year, month, day that are required to create a datetime object 
usertime = datetime.datetime(100,1,1, minute=minutes, second=seconds)

calculation = usertime - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1, seconds=8)
```

Now you can display the result of the time calculation however you like:

```
print('{minutes} minutes and {seconds} seconds'.format(minutes=calculation.minute, seconds=calculation.second))
# 4 minutes and 22 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression if the format will always be the same (but it probably will not), then convert the appropriate string to an integer/ double.

I think that you are going about this incorrectly. It would be best to have two separate input fields that only accept integers. One for minutes and one for seconds. If you want more precision (i.e milliseconds) then just include another input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

question = "How long is the video (mm:ss)? "
how_long = input(question).strip()

while not re.match(r"^[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d$", how_long): # regex to check if mm:ss digits are in range 0-5
    how_long = input("Wrong format. " + question).strip()

mm_ss = how_long.split(":")
how_long_obj = datetime.strptime(f"{mm_ss[0]}:{mm_ss[1]}", '%M:%S')
print(f"{how_long_obj - timedelta(seconds=68):%M:%S}")
```

---

**Output:**

```
How long is the video (mm:ss)? 22:33
21:25
```

---

[Python3 Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/QOT) - (Please turn Interactive mode `On`)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is the format in which you will accept the input. You could force the user to input the time in *just one format*, for example, **hours:minutes:seconds**, in that case, the code below will calculate the total seconds:

```python
inp = input('Video duration: ').split(':')
hours = 0
mins = 0
secs = 0

if len(inp) >= 3:
    hours = int(inp[-3])
if len(inp) >= 2:
    mins = int(inp[-2])
secs = int(inp[-1])

total_secs = hours * 3600 + mins * 60 + secs - 68
```

I oversimplified the code, it doesnt avoid user errors and edge cases